# Undefined 'err' in SQLX when initializing connecting to a database

Tags: go, sqlx

I am new to Go lang and trying to connect to the server and create a database upon an API call.

But I am getting an "undefined:err" at `sqlx.Connect`. Initially I thought it was because of me not defining the `db *sqlx.DB`. But it still gets error at `db, err = sqlx.Connect("mysql", connection)`.

Is it necessary to define a `var err` ?

```
func (setupController *SetupController) Setup(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var db *sqlx.DB
    var connection string

    response := new(Response)
    response.Host = r.FormValue("host")
    response.Port = r.FormValue("port")
    response.Dbuser = r.FormValue("dbuser")
    response.Dbpassword = r.FormValue("dbpassword")
    response.Dbname = r.FormValue("dbname")
    response.Username = r.FormValue("username")
    response.Password = r.FormValue("password")

    connection = response.Dbuser + ":" + response.Dbpassword + "@tcp(" + response.Host + ":" + response.Port + ")/" + response.Dbname
    db, err = sqlx.Connect("mysql", connection)
    userJson, err := json.Marshal(response)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    w.Write(userJson)
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very basic Go. You should do the tour. In particular have a look at https://tour.golang.org/basics/10.  Not that in Go you have to watch for the subtle difference between `=` and `:=`.

But in brief you are using `err` before it is declared.  You can either declare it first:

```
  var err error
```

or use a short declaration

```
  db, err := sqlx.Connect("mysql", connection)
```

Maybe easiest is to move the following line (which does do short declaration) before it otherwise you will get another error when it's declared twice.  And you probably should also check the error.

```
  userJson, err := json.Marshal(response)
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }
  db, err = sqlx.Connect("mysql", connection)
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }
```

However, I can see further problems beside this syntax error.

Comment: if i am using ```db, err := sqlx.Connect("mysql",connection)``` then there's no need for me to declare it at the anymore. Thank you for the explanation. Could you also point out any other syntax error here? I'm still in learning progress

Comment: @kurapika you need to `Close` the `db`, or else your app will run out of available connections very quickly. This is documented in [`database/sql`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/) which [`sqlx`](https://godoc.org/github.com/jmoiron/sqlx#DB) relies upon.